# Can't run sample console app after installing .NET core on ubuntu 19.10

Tags: c#, ubuntu, .net-core, sdk

After installing .NET core sdk according to instructions from:

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/linux-package-manager/ubuntu19-04/sdk-current

I created a sample console app with
`dotnet new console`. Running `dotnet run` gives the following error:

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (2): No such file or directory
>   at System.Diagnostics.Process.ForkAndExecProcess(String filename,
>   String[] argv, String[] envp, String cwd, Boolean redirectStdin,
>   Boolean redirectStdout, Boolean redirectStderr, Boolean
>   setCredentials, UInt32 userId, UInt32 groupId, UInt32[] groups, Int32&
>   stdinFd, Int32& stdoutFd, Int32& stderrFd, Boolean usesTerminal,
>   Boolean throwOnNoExec)    at
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)    at
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()    at
>   Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils.Command.Execute()    at
>   Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Run.RunCommand.Execute()    at
>   Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Run.RunCommand.Run(String[] args)    at
>   Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.ProcessArgs(String[] args, ITelemetry
>   telemetryClient)    at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.Main(String[]
>   args)

My `dotnet --info`:

```
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   3.0.100
 Commit:    04339c3a26

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     ubuntu
 OS Version:  19.10
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         ubuntu.19.10-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.0.100/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.0.0
  Commit:  95a0a61858

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  3.0.100 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.0.0 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.0.0 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

Notice that my version is 19.10. Could this really be the cause?

*.csproj

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: How does you *.csproj looks like?

Comment: I wrote up what you said [in a `Dockerfile`](https://gist.github.com/omajid/e4dfe808b9eba4810cdfe9b636414013). I get a working `Hello World!` at the end. What are you doing differently?

Comment: @OmairMajid I did ran your Dockerfile and I do get a `Hello World!` as well. No idea what is wrong..

Comment: Can you `strace` it? Something like `strace -e trace=%process -fo strace.log dotnet run`. Maybe upload the `strace.log` somewhere. I would love to know what is being `execve`d.

Comment: I was getting an error from OmniSharp extension for VS Code as well, which I don't have now, and I thought it was irrelevant. Creating a new console app works fine. I 'll have a look through the extension logs.

Comment: It seems as if OmniSharp couldn't locate the sdk. Maybe a restart fixed it? [OmniSharp log](https://gist.github.com/aris1009/8caf2595ee7b074d6f44a925d6ae04c6)